# Java instantiate generic hashmap value

Tags: java, generics

I have the following java code

```
public class QuestionBuilder {

private QuestionBuilder(){}

static HashMap<Long,Class<? extends Question>> questionIdMap;

static{
    questionIdMap = new HashMap();
    questionIdMap.put(1L, LicenseNumberQuestion.class);
    questionIdMap.put(2L, USPQuestion.class);
}



static Question getQuestion(long questionId)
{
    if(!questionIdMap.containsKey(questionId))
    {
        throw new BusinessProfileInputException("Add an id to question class map entry");
    }

     return questionIdMap.get(questionId).newInstance();

}
```

}

and I would like my getQuestion method to return me a new instance of the class that was specified as a value in the map as is intended via my code. Howerver the last line of code does not compile :

return questionIdMap.get(questionId).newInstance();

Am I thinking of this wrongly? i.e. is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: What is the compile error you get?

Comment: `questionIdMap = new HashMap();` should be `questionIdMap = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
public final class QuestionBuilder {

    private QuestionBuilder(){}

    public enum Type {

        LICENSE_NUMBER {
            @Override
            Question getQuestion() { return new LicenseNumberQuestion(); }
        },
        USP {
            @Override
            Question getQuestion() { return new USPQuestion(); }
        };

        abstract Question getQuestion();
    }

    public static Question getQuestion(Type type) {
        return type.getQuestion();
    }
}
```

With your solution the user of the class has to write

```
Question question = QuestionBuilder.getQuestion(1);
```

This isn't great because it's not clear what "1" here means, and she is going to have to learn the meaning of a load of numbers. Also, if you pass in a number that doesn't mean anything, there's a problem (hence the need for a `BusinessProfileInputException`).

With the `enum` approach, the user of the class would write

```
Question question = QuestionBuilder.getQuestion(QuestionBuilder.Type.LICENSE_NUMBER);
```

Now this is obviously longer, but there are 3 major advantages. (1) The user of the class doesn't need to remember any abstract code numbers. In fact if the user is using a decent IDE, she should actually be presented with a meaningful list of choices as she types. (2) There is no longer the need for the `BusinessProfileInputException` because it is now *impossible* to pass something that doesn't mean anything (except `null`, but in this case a `NullPointerException` would be thrown anyway). (3) You no longer need reflection to create the new `Question`, so there is no need for the irritating `try` block.

But it's even better than this. You'll notice that since we've got rid of the `Map`, the class `QuestionBuilder` doesn't actually do *anything at all*. You could improve things further by getting rid of the class completely, and making the `enum` a top-level class with a simple name like `TypeOfQuestion`. Then all the user would have to type is

```
Question question = TypeOfQuestion.LICENSE_NUMBER.getQuestion();
```

`enum`s in Java are absolutely brilliant. They are far superior to the counterparts in other languages. I strongly recommend learning about them.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to catch an exception:

```
try {
    return questionIdMap.get(questionId).newInstance();
} catch(InstantiationException e) {
    System.out.println("Constructor failed: );
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

This should compile fine.

Comment: Thanks. As a followup...is this a fail-safe operation? is there any reason why this statement would throw a runtime exception after i've verified the key is in the map an the class has a public default constructor??

Comment: You are invoking the object's constructor. It could throw an exception. If it does, the exception will be wrapped into an `InstantiationException`, and caught here.
Because this is reflection, java cannot know at compile time what constructor is going to be called, and what it may throw so `newInstance()` is declared to throw an `InstantiationException` no matter what. Now, why the hell  you have to always catch all exceptions that can possibly be thrown in java, is a different question ... I don't think *anyone* knows an answer to that one :)

Comment: @Dima It's annoying, but I find it useful as it warns you about potential problems and makes you consider alternative approaches. In this example, the checked exception is a clue that reflection isn't the best approach at all. Instead of questionIdMap there should be an enum with values LICENCE_NUMBER, USP... and a method getInstance overridden by each enum constant which returns a new instance without using reflection. That way Questions are not required to have parameterless constructors, and you don't need the BusinessProfileInputException either...

Comment: I'm not familiar with coding up the idiom "an enum with values and a method overridden by each enum constant"? Mind posting a minor example of what that looks like? Somewhat new to java and enums seem to be more powerful than in other languages.

Comment: @pbabcdefp it's debatable. I am not sure what exactly you have in mind when you are saying that "reflection isn't best approach at all". The only potential problem with reflection I can think of is performance, unless you are creating hundreds of these objects per second, it doesn't matter. Enum approach may be faster, but it is more code (=== more bugs), harder to read and understand what's going on, and harder to maintain and extend (adding new subclasses requires making changes to unrelated code).

Comment: @cclusetti I've posted my enum approach. enums are well worth learning.

Comment: @Dima Sorry i wasn't at all clear how I would get rid of the Exception. I've posted a possible approach. By the way, I'm completely with you on how irritating java's checked exceptions are - I just think that sometimes they can help you out.